# Jupiter notebook.- ImportError: No module named cv2

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I´m trying to import open cv using Jupyter Notebook, from Anaconda 3 but when I run the command `import cv2` i get this error `ImportError: No module named cv2`.

The strange thing is that when i run the same comand on Spyder(From Anaconda 3 too) dont have any problem. And I need use specifically Jupyter notebook

What should I do in order to make this work?

Comment: What's the output of  `import site;print(site.getsitepackages()[0]` (launched inside a cell)?

Comment: We're going to need some information on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Start Jupyter from your command shell after activating Anaconda, e.g.

```
c:\> conda activate
(base) c:\> jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install CV2 into an anaconda environment. So first you have to select the environment that you want to install it in. You do this with conda. Open a terminal then type

````
conda activate environment

```
where your environment is an environment you have set up in anaconda. IF you have not created any environments then you have a base environment called base so use that
````